# Angular http get request do nothing

Tags: angular, angular-http

So, I'm trying to make a request to an API (for example the SWAPI API)

In my app.module :

```js
...
...
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientTestingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In my Component I do like so :

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.studyService.getSWAPI_List().subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response)
    }, error => {console.log(error)});
    this.studyService.getSWAPI_List2().subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response)
    }, error => {console.log(error)});

  }
```

In my service :

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

const options =  {
  headers: new  HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getSWAPI_List(){
    console.log('Request SWAPI list')
    return this.http.get('https://swapi.dev/api/people/', options);
  }

  getSWAPI_List2(){
    console.log('Request SWAPI list2')
    return this.http.get('https://swapi.dev/api/people/');
  }
}
```

And in my browser console, I don't see any response ( for both requests with and without the header) but if I use this simple URL in my browser everything works fine ...

I also have no error in the console (and in the network tab of the console) ...

Can someone help me to see why?

Comment: did you include `` HttpClientModule`` ??

Comment: yes, i will add my configuration in my question

Comment: Hello,
is your component which used for http calls is in the same App.module ? or in another module ?

Comment: my component call correctly the console.log() in my service so everything there is okay, I really think that the problem is in the HTTP request but I don't see why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code seems correct at a first glance.
Also my [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xegzc7) works as expected.

console output:

```
Request SWAPI list
Request SWAPI list2
Angular is running in development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable production mode.
{count: 82, next: "http://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=2", previous: null, results: Array[10]…}
{count: 82, next: "http://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=2", previous: null, results: Array[10]…}
```

I suggest that you post more info or update the Stackblitz example, to find your real issue.

You can also download the Stackblitz example
[image: Stackblitz example]
to check if it works on your local dev-machine.

Comment: i downloaded and run the stackblitz example and every thing is fine there ... I guess I will have to find where I don't do the same things as you ... thanks

Comment: yes - maybe some different versions of packages, other imports, ..

Comment: I just tried to do a npm install to check and I have a lot of error

Comment: then post another question related to those npm errors

Comment: I recreated all from the start, and I worked ... thanks a lot nether the less